Cannot access ethernet camera from within docker container
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Pylon: pylon_7.5.0.15658-deb0_amd64
The camera is connected to ethernet interface enp0s31f6 which is on static ip 192.168.2.10/255.255.255.0. The camera is on static ip 192.168.2.11/255.255.255.0.
I built pylon-ros-camera and it successfully detected the camera

But even though I successfully built the same package inside a docker container, it cannot detect the camera.

What I tried

To allow the container to see the interfaces on the host, I run the container with networking as docker run --network=host -d myimage .... And now if I run ifconfig inside the container, it shows me the same interfaces as on the host. See below ifconfig output on host and inside container. But, it still cannot detect the camera.
I ran the container with extended privileges as docker run --network=host --privileged -v /dev:/dev -d .... But, it still cannot detect the camera.

What might be the problem?
IFCONFIG on host
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:cff:fe29:3048  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:0c:29:30:48  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 602988  bytes 31801390 (31.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 701650  bytes 5591761213 (5.5 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::ada5:60b0:e461:3007  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9c:6b:00:07:61:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10880082  bytes 16425539680 (16.4 GB)
        RX errors 9  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 9
        TX packets 54503  bytes 3794035 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  memory 0x72500000-72520000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 240419  bytes 70007245 (70.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 240419  bytes 70007245 (70.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.19  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::40ef:b0b9:5215:18e7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f0:b6:1e:a2:b6:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6337099  bytes 8614290755 (8.6 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6672  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1492973  bytes 542835548 (542.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

IFCONFIG inside container
root@docker-desktop:/home/basler_ws# ifconfig
br-aa73862743b3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:18ff:fe68:6f5e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:18:68:6f:5e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12  bytes 699 (699.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17  bytes 12202 (12.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-fb4a1a6ffdce: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::42:12ff:feaf:abcc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:12:af:ab:cc  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26  bytes 4052 (4.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68  bytes 13912 (13.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:be:4c:46:18  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.65.9  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.65.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:12:34:56  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 19853  bytes 2562859 (2.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18195  bytes 7005442 (7.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 140  bytes 18520 (18.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 140  bytes 18520 (18.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

services1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.65.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::3c19:b1ff:fe38:ffcb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3e:19:b1:38:ff:cb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 46  bytes 3709 (3.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 83  bytes 15611 (15.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth150498a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::30b3:9eff:fe24:7a7a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 32:b3:9e:24:7a:7a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26  bytes 4416 (4.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 109  bytes 19474 (19.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


Why it's voted to close? What's wrong with the question?

I guess you have to address Basler support directly on that. I recall to have had some blocking issues with docker as well, probably due to low level filter driver that Basler uses to intercept UDP stream.
